# Does Apple still produce installer discs for OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, install

Does Apple still produce installer discs for OS X? I know that they have made discs for OS X in the past, but I have not been able to find any online. Does Apple still create these discs?

Comment: For which OSX version?

Comment: Sorry I was attempting to answer my own question as a source of reference for others. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

No, Apple has discontinued physical install discs since 2011. The last version of OS X that was able to be purchased on a disc was OS X Snow Leopard (10.6). Now, you will need to buy a installable USB for the operating system you want, if it is 10.7 or above. Anything below 10.6 still has a physical disc for its operating system.